# How does tagging affect searchability?

Tags: discussion, tags

Suppose I have this question

> **How does MySuperSecretLanguage's garbage collection work?**
>
> I am wondering how the garbage collector in MySuperSecretLanguage works. Can someone please explain?
>
> [mysupersecretlanguage](/questions/tagged/mysupersecretlanguage)

and these two queries

[image]

[image]

Would adding the [garbage-collection](/questions/tagged/garbage-collection) tag improve my search rank for the first query? Could it decrease my rank for the second query? I don't know much about search engine optimization, but I have a suspicion that adding tags would decrease the "value" of existing ones due to pollution.

Comment: I don't know, but I suspect that the difference, if any, is very small. I do know that as users we are not supposed to optimize for Google searchability. Doing so can often lead to decreased user experience with very little gain from the SEO.

Comment: @murgatroid99 Can you back up the statement *"We are not supposed to optimize for Google searchability."*?

Comment: @murgtroid99 Thanks for the link. I didn't get the kind of in depth statistics I was looking for, but the question is indeed an exact duplicate. I started a close vote.